# Is my destructor giving me this error: *** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop):?

Tags: c++, linux, class, destructor

This is the instructions for my assignment: 
The Copy Constructor.  The copy constructor should perform a deep copy of the argument object, i.e. it should construct an IntCollection with the same size and capacity as the argument, with its own complete copy of the argument's data array.

The Assignment Operator (=). The assignment operator should also perform a deep copy of the argument object.  It must return itself (or more efficiently, a reference to itself) in order tosupport multiple assignments on the same line, e.g. a = b = c.  If you implement your assignment operator first it could be used in the copy constructor, but this is not a requirement.

The Is Equals operator (==). The "is equals" operator should return true if the argument object has the same size as the receiving object, and the values in both objects’ data arrays are identical.

The insertion operator (<<). The insertion operator should add the int parameter into the receiving IntCollection.  The functionality is exactly the same as the add() function, i.e. add ints to the collection.  Note, however, that this function must return a reference to itself in order to support multiple insertions on the same line, e.g. c << 45 << -210.  Unlike the assignment operator, this return must be done by reference, because each insertion actually modifies the IntCollection object, and insertion is done from left to right.

**The destructor. Function add() calls addCapacity() to allocate memory when it needs more room.  Nowhere in this program is the memory deallocated with delete [], which means we have a memory leak!  Add a destructor which correctly handles this.**

addCapacity.  Note that addCapacity() is a private member function.  What happens if you try to call it from outside the class, i.e. by adding the line below to main()?

c.addCapacity();

Here is my code: 
**IntCollection.h:**

```
#ifndef INTCOLLECTION_H
#define INTCOLLECTION_H

// Allocate memory in chunks of ints of this size.
const int CHUNK_SIZE = 5;

class IntCollection
{
  private:
  // The number of ints currently stored in the int
    int size;
  // the total number of elements available for storage
  // in the data array
    int capacity;
  // A pointer to the dynamically allocated data array
    int* data;
  // a private member function to allocate more memory 
  // if necessary
    void addCapacity();
  public:
  // Constructor
    IntCollection();
  // Destructor
    ~IntCollection();
  // Copy constructor:
    IntCollection(const IntCollection &c);

    void add(int value);
    int get(int index);
    int getSize();
    IntCollection& operator=(const IntCollection &c);
    bool operator==(const IntCollection &c);
    IntCollection& operator<<(int value);
};

#endif
```

**IntCollection.cpp:**

```
#include "IntCollection.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

IntCollection::IntCollection() 
{
    // Initialize member data to reflect an empty
    // IntCollection
    size = capacity = 0;
    data = NULL;
}

IntCollection::~IntCollection() 
{
    delete [] data;
}

IntCollection::IntCollection(const IntCollection &c) {
    size = c.size;
    capacity = c.capacity;
    data = c.data;

    for (int i = 0; i < c.size; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = c.data[i];
    }
}

void IntCollection::addCapacity() 
{
    // Create a new, bigger buffer, copy the current data to
    // it, delete the old buffer, and point our data
    // pointer to the new buffer
    int *newData;
    data = new int[capacity];
    capacity += CHUNK_SIZE;
    newData = new int[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        newData[i] = data[i];
        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
}

void IntCollection::add(int value) 
{
    // first, allocate more memory if we need to
    if (size == capacity) 
    {
        addCapacity();
    }
    // Now, add the data to our array and increment size
    data[size++] = value;
}

int IntCollection::get(int index) 
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) 
    {
        cout << "ERROR: get() trying to access index out of range.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return data[index];
}

int IntCollection::getSize() 
{
    return size;
}

IntCollection &IntCollection::operator=(const IntCollection &c) 
{
    size = c.size;
    capacity = c.capacity;
    data = c.data;

    return *this;
}

bool IntCollection::operator==(const IntCollection &c) 
{
    if ((size == c.size) && (capacity == c.capacity)) 
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < size; m++) 
        {
            if (data[m] == c.data[m]) 
            {
                continue;
            } else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

IntCollection &IntCollection::operator<<(int value) 
{
    add(value);
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "IntCollection.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  IntCollection c;

  c.add(45);
  c.add(-210);
  c.add(77);
  c.add(2);
  c.add(-21);
  c.add(42);
  c.add(7);

  for (int i = 0; i < c.getSize(); i++)
  {
    cout << c.get(i) << endl;
  }

  IntCollection d(c);
  for (int i = 0; i < c.getSize(); i++)
  {
    cout << c.get(i) << endl;
  }

  IntCollection e;
  e = c;
  cout << "Testing = Overload" << endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < c.getSize(); i++)
  {
    cout << c.get(i) << endl;
  }

  IntCollection f;
  f<<8<<9<<10;
  cout << "Testing<<Overload" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < f.getSize(); i++)
  {
    cout << f.get(i) << endl;
  }

  cout << "Testing == Overload" << endl;

  c.add(10);

  if(f == c)
  {
    cout << "Both objects match" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "They don't match" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After I believed that I fixed most of my errors, I get this as my output:

```
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000b2ec80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7ff7e6f70bfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7ff7e6f76fc6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7780e)[0x7ff7e6f7780e]
./main[0x400fa1]
./main[0x400fe2]
./main[0x400aa2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7ff7e6f202e1]
./main[0x40097a]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11008976                           /home/runner/main
```

I won't post all of it because it is long. Is my destructor causing this? I am not sure how to fix this nor have I ever encountered this error before.

Comment: Run this in a debugger.  The "double free" error means that you are calling `delete` on the same pointer multiple times.  Can you find the `delete` that's doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This line, from your copy constructor, is the likely problem:

```
data = c.data;
```

After that line, you have *two* object pointing *to the **same** data*. It is a *shallow* copy.

If one of the objects are destructed then if will `delete[]` the data, leaving the other object with an invalid pointer. When the second objects destructor then tries to `delete[]` the data (again!) it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to do a *deep* copy, which is the assignment you have. That includes a *new* memory allocation and actually copying the data.

Same thing with the copy-assignment operator.